# Can any one help me how i will bulkify my trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, bulkification

```
/*
    Name - ConatctAccountTrigger

    Purpose -   Contact records will be created via data loader. 
                This trigger reads Buyer ID and ASAP Tower ID from contact, searches account for Buyer Id and ASAP Tower ID then 
                sets the account ID on the Contact record.


Version     Author              Date            Details 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1.0         Offshore            05/14/2015      Created the trigger
1.1         Offshore            07/13/2016      Created the trigger
********************************************************************************************************************
*/

trigger ConatctAccountTrigger on Contact (before update, before insert) {

    for(Contact cntc : trigger.new){

        //Proceed if accountID is null      
        if(cntc.accountId == null){
            //try{
            //Proceed if Buyer ID available
            if(cntc.Buyer_ID__c != null){

                List<Account> accnts = [Select Id from Account where Buyer_ID__c=:cntc.Buyer_ID__c];

                //Proceed only if one Account is found
                //If more than one Account records are found, skip Contact record
                //If no Account record is found,  skip Contact record               
                if(accnts.size() == 1){

                    cntc.accountId = accnts[0].Id;

                }               
            }
            //Proceed if ASAP Tower ID available
            if(cntc.ASAP_Tower_ID__c!= null){

                List<Account> accnts = [Select Id from Account where ASAP_Tower_ID__c=:cntc.ASAP_Tower_ID__c ];

                //Proceed only if one Account is found
                //If more than one Account records are found, skip Contact record
                //If no Account record is found,  skip Contact record               
                if(accnts.size() == 1){

                    cntc.accountId = accnts[0].Id;

                }               
              }
            //}
            //catch(Exception e){
           //system.debug ('Error Relating contact to Account');
        //}       
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The collections based approach is fairly standard here. Build your filter collection, then map your query back by the filtered field.

```
Set<Id> buyerIds = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> asapIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Contact record : trigger.new)
{
    buyerIds.add(record.ASAP_Tower_Id__c);
    asapIds.add(record.ASAP_Tower_Id__c);
}
Map<String, Account> buyerMap = new Map<String, Account>();
Map<String, Account> asapMap = new Map<String, Account>();
for (Account record : [
    SELECT Buyer_Id__c, ASAP_Tower_Id__c FROM Account
    WHERE Buyer_Id__c IN :buyerIds OR ASAP_Tower_Id__c IN :asapIds
]){
    buyerMap.put(record.Buyer_Id__c, record);
    asapMap.put(record.ASAP_Tower_Id__c, record);
}
```

Now inside your loop, you can get records from the map instead of querying for them.

```
for (Contact record : trigger.new)
{
    if (buyerMap.containsKey(record.Buyer_Id__c))
        record.AccountId = buyerMap.get(record.Buyer_Id__c).Id;
    else if (asapMap.containsKey(record.ASAP_Tower_Id__c))
        record.AccountId = asapMap.get(record.ASAP_Tower_Id__c).Id;
}
```

Comment: this solution is not working for me. not updating account id in contact on basis of ASAP Tower id.